# best tiny css mobile framework that support rtl

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, mobile, mobile-development

im using jquery mobile framework for my phonegap project but as jqmobile make a lot of modification on the HTML i faced many problem and i want to change it to a verry tiny css mobile framework that support RTL direction .

why i want to use mobile css frameworks ? because i want to apply the navigation bar (left and right) and a fixed header for iOS(6.0+) , android(2.2+) , wp8 and blackberry in the same way so i didn't find a good framework that support that except jquery mobile.

Answer (score 1):

here are some css frameworks with rtl support:

- ZURB Foundation has native [rtl component](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/rtl.html)
- [YAML CSS framework](http://www.yaml.de/) has native support for rtl
- Bootstrap has an RTL Theme (look for bootstrap-rtl on github)
- FlipCSS is a tool for creating rtl css from your ltr css(you can find it on github)

IMHO your best bet for mobile app will be ZURB's Foundation. It has built in support for mobile layouts and rtl handling.

Having said that, I don't think any of above will work good with jQuery mobile. You will have to rewrite your navigation bar using css framework.